# SQL Server Compact - Schema Management

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I've been searching for some time for a good solution to implement the idea of managing schema on an [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) 3.5 database.

I know of several ways of managing schema on [SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express), SQL Server Standard, SQL Server Enterprise, but the Compact Edition doesn't support the necessary tools required to use the same methodology.

Any suggestions/tips?

---

I should expand this to say that it is for 100+ clients with wrapperware software.  As the system changes, I need to publish update scripts alongside the new binaries to the client.  I was looking for a decent method by which to publish this without having to just hand the client a script file and say "Run this in SSMSE".  Most clients are not capable of doing such a beast.

A buddy of mine disclosed a partial script on how to handle the SQL Server piece of my task, but never worked on Compact Edition. It looks like I'll be on my own for this.

What I think that I've decided to do, and it's going to need a "geek week" to accomplish, is to write some sort of a tool much like how [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) and [NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt) works, so that I can just write an overzealous XML document to handle the work.

If I think that it is worthwhile, I'll publish it on CodePlex and/or [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) because I've used both sites a bit to gain better understanding of concepts for jobs I've done in the past, and I think it is probably worthwhile to give back a little.

---

Edit on 5/3/2010:

If someone is willing to "name" the project, I'll upload the dirty/nasty version that I've written for MS SQL to CodePlex so that maybe we can start hacking out a version of SQL Compact.  Although, I think with the next revision of the initial application that I was planning, I'm going to be abandoning SQL Compact and just use XML Files for storage, as the software is being converted from an Installable package to being a Silverlight application.  Silverlight just gives a better access strategy.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently looking into [Migrator.Net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/).
This allows you to write changes to your database, called migrations, directly in C#.
These migrations can contain everything from simple table additions/drops, column modifications, to complicated data update code.

When your application boots, it can verify what version the database is currently in and apply any migrations that are required to bring it up to date.  All this is handled automatically.  The code to run this update is as simple as:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("LocalModels.migration");
Migrator m = new Migrator("SqlServerCe", "Data Source=LocalModels.sdf", asm, false);
m.MigrateToLastVersion();
```

I am having a couple minor issues with the Compact support (it assumes the default schema is dbo).  But I don't think it will be too difficult to fix them.

Comment: That's pretty cool all-in-all, considering that looks to be a database independent solution.  I may indeed need to look at that.

Comment: I have been using Migrator.Net for a while.  The project is abandoned, but it works fine for me.  I have made some changes, most of them project specific.  Fixing the bug with Compact did turn out to be easy, though I have migrated to SQLite since then.  I can post my updates to github if they would be useful to someone.

Comment: wondering how it works currently with PostgreSQL, as that's the db platform I'm working with these days.  Seriously thinking of writing my own so it's not an NIH solution that causes more issues than it solves.

Comment: I don't know how it's PostgreSQL support is.  I would recommend starting with Migrator.Net and building what you need off of it.  It is not a complex project and the code is clean and simple.  It would probably be much easier to start with it as a base than roll your own from scratch.

Comment: Wound up using FluentMigrations which if I understand correctly is the reboot of Migrator.NET.  Now that I'm familiar with it, it's quite an impressive tool.

Answer (score 0):

some random thoughts (not sure I can fully answer though)

1. the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C88BA2D1-CEF3-4149-B301-9B056E7FB1E6&displaylang=en) is one option.  I haven't had a chance to fully appreciate what it can do once you've deployed it after the initial first time (which seems to work fine).  There's a MSDN site for it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx)
2. You can execute scripts on a mobile device, but not through something like SQL Management Studio, so in theory you could manage/maintain T-SQL scripts but the down side is that the T-SQL would be convoluted (to CE's supported statements) and I don't know a way to "automate" execution - but the Sync Framework might hold some answers..

Comment: Using the Sync Framework... that is to move data between a full-blown copy of SQL server and a satellite copy of the data.

My point was how are folks that do mobile development handling database changes as their software evolves?

Comment: You can also AFAIK handle schema changes with it also

Comment: You "Can", but its a very messy proposition with the way the Fx works.  To actually make schema changes, dependent on what you are doing, you have to recreate the table with the new schema, move the data from the old table to the new one, delete existing, and rename new. :(

Comment: (Continuing)... That's not kosher to me, as for some of the schema changes I need to do, it will mark the whole table as needing to be synched... and I do not agree with that being a decent solution.  I need this to run over a dialup/3G card pipe, so I want to keep things lean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your key criteria is going to be working efficiently over a small pipe, the only real choice you have is to store a DB Schema Version (maybe somehow tied to the scripts checked into your CMS) and when an update is needed, the change scripts are sent over the wire and applied in order. You would probably want to keep a log in your DB as well of these scripts being applied so you can gracefully handle disconnects, reboots and other potentially nasty problems.

Answer (score -2):

Is SQL Server Management Studio any use for you?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172933.aspx

Comment: Damian.. I don't think you've read the post... and maybe I need to make this clearer... I'm needing to publish update scripts to 100+ clients... I need a way that the application can handle the updates for me.

I've actually decided to build my own method, using Xml, so that it performs much like what you have in tools like nAnt and WiX.  It just sucks that no-one has ever done this before... that I cannot just snipe a copy, edit for my use, and be done with it.

Comment: @RichardB My answer was added *before* you modified your question to mention that you needed to do this on 100+ machines, so yes, I *did* read the post. I wouldn't normally come back on a comment such as this but it appears that I have received a couple of down votes as a result, which is annoying to say the least.

Comment: apologies.  I get the same thing, and must not have realized it.  Do you know of any way that I can purge the comment above so that you don't get burned?  I've gotten that once or twice myself.

Comment: I actually abandoned what I wrote at that time to use Fluent Migrator.  Great project, and it works for 99% of what I've needed.  I've had to fudge a few use cases that they present to do a few of the items, but not much.  You should check it out on github.  Honestly tho, I've completely abandoned SQL Compact for SQLite, and may even abandon SQLite for a NOSQL Solution.